# PHP - List all days in a month in a year

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have 2 dates in PHP, how can I run a foreach loop to go through all of those days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207749/i-have-2-dates-in-php-how-can-i-run-a-foreach-loop-to-go-through-all-of-those-d)

I'm new to PHP. How can I be able to list all days in a year? (or from a given date?)

What I would like to do is generate a form with all the days in a month, so I can fill in a budget. And it should end by the end of the year, but it should be able to start from a random date.

Any examples on how I should do this? I should also be able to see the name of the date. Example "**21 May - Monday** " and list all days and months until 2013.

Comment: Try checking out `strtotime()`. [Heres a good tutorial](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-loop-through-dates-from-date-to-date-with-strtotime-function/).

Comment: try to use jquery date picker for this purpose it might be pretty easier

Comment: Much better tutorial: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php :-)

Comment: @eisberg IMO the other tutorial is more suited to what the OP wants.

Answer (score 5):

You could use this, but there could be a more elegant way:

```
$start_date = '2012-06-01'; // Give in your own start date
$start_day = date('z', strtotime($start_date)); // 6th of June
$days_in_a_year = date('z', strtotime('2012-12-31')); // 31th of december

$number_of_days = ($days_in_a_year - $start_day) +1 ; // Add the last of december also
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_days; $i++) {
    $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date)) . " +$i day");
    echo date('d F - l', $date) .'<br />';
}
```