# Using the date() function, how to get each day of month?

Tags: php, date

Using the PHP `date()` function, or any other underlining function like `cal_days_in_month`, how would I print each day in a specific month?

Thank ye, thank ye!

I would like some sort of output like this:

(maybe done with a `foreach` loop?)

```
...whatever day name starts the month
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
...ect
until end of month
```

Comment: can you clear with example

Comment: Can you show the output you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following function that I wrote will do it.

```
<?php

function calendar ($month, $year)
{
    $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
    $today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d")); 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
    {
        $date = strtotime($year . "-" . $month . "-" . ($i + 1));
        if ($today === $date)
        {
            echo ("!!");
        }
        $day=strftime("%A", $date);
        echo (($i + 1) . " " . $day . "<BR>");
    }
}
?>
```

EDITED: Now includes request.

Comment: Thanks! And then from there, how could I detect which date echoed is the date of today?

Comment: Edited post to include that.

Answer (score 1):

This one should give you the code to write the required function. There isn't an underlying PHP function that would do this.
[Grab all Wednesdays in a given month in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293174/grab-all-wednesdays-in-a-given-month-in-php)

Also see official php documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

[PHP - List all days in a month in a year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468223/php-list-all-days-in-a-month-in-a-year)

Do you have any code you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
function printDay($month,$year=FALSE){
    if(!$year){
        $year=date('Y');
    }
     $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year); 
     for($day=1;$day<=$num;$day++){

         echo date('l',  strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day));
         echo "<br>";
     }
}

printDay(8);
```