# get all the dates between start date and end date in php

Tags: php, date

I want to get all the dates between the start date and end date. I need to show a weekly data, and the data is split into day wise.

I have a start date as 2015-11-02 and end date as 2015-11-08. Then I need to print all the dates in between in a foreach loop.

How can I do that?

Comment: How is this duplicate?

Comment: @phantomphoenix: sometimes the answers are alreay there for you, they just need searching for.

Answer (score 0):

One could use string manipulation and basic math, but months with different number of days and leap years etc make this a futile approach.

It is better to use an instance of [PHP DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) and loop through that, which is a [question already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207749/i-have-2-dates-in-php-how-can-i-run-a-foreach-loop-to-go-through-all-of-those-d):

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2010-05-01' );
$end = new DateTime( '2010-05-10' );

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ( $period as $dt )
  echo $dt->format( "l Y-m-d H:i:s\n" );
```

The DateTime object has the added advantage of outputting various formats, useful when generating link names, URIs, SQL queries, etc.