# Update Automatic Mysql Values php

Tags: php

Hello I want to update MySQL table automatic at set time like i want to update table at 5:30 i have some values to update in my database at set time automatic. in `PHP`

```
$date = date('H:i:s');
if($date == "11:26:00") // 17:30:00 is equal to 5:30 but in 24 system 
{
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM No where id='1'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error());
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
    {
    $Foo= $row['foo'];
    }
    $sql2 = "UPDATE No SET id='2',foo='$foo' where id='2'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error());

}
```

Comment: you can use CRON for that

Comment: yea it only will work if its equal to 11:26 only , so you have to put a loop  so it can throw all the day and check if the date is equal to that time

Comment: no its not working i am using loop like this foreach ($date as $dates) then if ($dates == "11:26:00")

Answer (score 0):

Just lie what Ashish said you can use CRON , and if you want you maybe can use this , i did not use before , try it . This code will works once ,so you have to find away to make loop cause the time will change every sec .

Note  : Check the second code .

```
<?php 
    // Database connect

    $date = date('H:i:s'); // Set the time to hours and minutes and seconds format  
    // you can echo $date to check how it looks but it will be something like this : 07:21:48

    if($date == "17:30:00") // 17:30:00 is equal to 5:30 but in 24 system 
    {
        // You can type your code here . 

    }

 ?>
```

Second Code :

```
<?php

 // Remember to connect to your database    

$date1 = date_create("00:00");
$date2 = date_create("23:59");
while($date1<=$date2)
{
    date_add($date1,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 sec"));
    $a = date_format($date1,"H-i-s");
    if($a =='17:30:00')
    {
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM No where id='1'";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error());
            $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)
                {
                    $Foo= $row['foo'];
                    $sql2 = "UPDATE No SET id='2',foo='$foo' where id='2'";
                    $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error());
                }
            die;
       }
    else
      {
         // you can type anything here , you can end the process by typing die; or anything you want 
      }

}



?>
```

You can check this and see how you can loop throw date in php :

[I have 2 dates in PHP, how can I run a foreach loop to go through all of those days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207749/i-have-2-dates-in-php-how-can-i-run-a-foreach-loop-to-go-through-all-of-those-d)

This can help you understand the time and date system and how to change the format for the date in php : [How to get the current date and time in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/get-current-date-and-time-in-php)

Comment: @hanks ok im updating my answer

Comment: give me some time let me figure it out . ( Time loop)

Comment: @hanks check the new answer and check the second code .

Comment: if the above code works then all what you have to do is to change $date1 to the current time for your server

Comment: @hanks just edited the answer, and edited the mysqli part , and want to ask this , whats the error that shows up to you ?

Comment: OK so empty page ?

Comment: Yes Maybe Code not trigger