# How to generate an array in PHP and JSON encode?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to create a JSON format of an array using PHP, but my result is only the latest data and is being replaced.

How can I show all days?

#### Code:

```
for($i=1;$i<5;$i++) { 
  $ar -> date = date("j F y",strtotime("+".$i." days"));
  $ar -> id = $i;
}

echo json_encode($ar);
```

#### Current result:

```
{"date":"8 May 19","id":4}
```

Comment: You may also find [I have 2 dates in PHP, how can I run a foreach loop to go through all of those days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207749/i-have-2-dates-in-php-how-can-i-run-a-foreach-loop-to-go-through-all-of-those-d) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an array to store the values into so that you don't overwrite them on each pass through the loop:

```
$ar = array();
for($i=1;$i<5;$i++) { 
  $ar[] = array('date' => date("j F y",strtotime("+".$i." days")), 'id' => $i);
}
echo json_encode($ar);
```

Output:

```
[
 {"date":"5 May 19","id":1},
 {"date":"6 May 19","id":2},
 {"date":"7 May 19","id":3},
 {"date":"8 May 19","id":4}
]
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/nhUSV)

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_push to do that also:

```
$ar = array();
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    array_push($ar, ["id" => $i, "date" => date("j F y", strtotime("+" . $i . " days"))]);
}

$ar = json_encode($ar);
var_dump($ar);
```

#### Output

> string(109) "[{"id":1,"date":"5 May 19"},{"id":2,"date":"6 May
>   19"},{"id":3,"date":"7 May 19"},{"id":4,"date":"8 May 19"}]"

Answer (score 1):

You can create array with custom field name

```
      <?php

      $AR = array();
      for($i=1;$i<5;$i++) {
        $a=array();
        $a['id']=$i;
        $a['date'] = date("j F y",strtotime("+".$i." days"));
        $AR[]=$a;
      }
      echo json_encode($AR); ?>
```

output :

```
      [{"id":1,"date":"5 May 19"},{"id":2,"date":"6 May 19"},{"id":3,"date":"7 May 19"},{"id":4,"date":"8 May 19"}]
```