# compare two JSON objects array and print specific content in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, date

I have JSON objects array as shown below. The following content is in the file **(feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json)** mentioned at Line A.

```
{
    "house_sitting_date_current_month": ["2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-02-03", "2020-02-04", "2020-02-05", "2020-02-06"],
    "house_sitting_date_yes_no_current_month": ["yes", "nada", "nada", "nada", "yes", "yes"],
    "house_sitting_date_next_month": ["2020-03-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-03", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-05", "2020-03-06"],
    "house_sitting_date_yes_no_next_month": ["no", "yes", "yes", "nada", "nada", "nada"],
    "toggle_status": null
}
```

For every particular date there is a value **(yes/no/nada)** associated with it.

For the current month **($data_house->house_sitting_date_current_month)**; **Feb 1st**, **Feb 5th** and **Feb 6th** have **yes** (rest all are nada). 
For the next month **($data_house->house_sitting_date_next_month)**; **March 2nd** and **March 3rd** have **yes**. **March 1st** is **No** (rest all are nada).

**Here is the php code:**

```
<?php

if (file_exists('feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json')) {
    $data_house = json_decode(file_get_contents('feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json'));  // Line A
}

$date = date("Y-m-d");

$sitting_day_str_en = "Sitting day";

$not_a_sitting_day_str_en ="Not a Sitting Day";


?>

<header class="entry-header container">
   <?php
      the_title('<h1 class="entry-title-house">', '</h1>');
    ?>
   <span class="current-date"><?php echo $date ?></span><!-- prints today's date--> // Line B 
         <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en') { ?>        <!-- English -->
                <span class="current-date-answer">Sitting Day</span> // Line C                           
        <?php } ?>
</header>
```

**Problem Statement:**

At present I have hard-coded **Sitting Day** at Line C

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above **(specially at Line C)** so that **Line B** looks/match/scan `($data_house->house_sitting_date_current_month, $data_house->house_sitting_date_next_month)` for a date inside the JSON above 
and print content at **Line C** on the basis of **today's date** in the **JSON**.

**Case 1:** If today's date is **2020-02-1** at **Line B** and its **yes** for the corresponding date in the JSON, then it should say Sitting Day at **Line C**.

**Case 2:** If today's date is **2020-03-01** at Line B and its **no** for the corresponding date in the JSON, then it should say Not a Sitting Day at **Line C**.

**Case 3:** If today's date is **2020-03-06** at **Line B** and **nada** is present in the JSON for that particular date, then it should say display blank/nothing at **Line C**.

I think, we need to use two foreach loops but more need to be done.

```
<?php foreach ($data_house->house_sitting_date_current_month as $key1 => $val1) {
    foreach ($data_house->house_sitting_date_yes_no_current_month as $key1 => $val1) {


}} ?>


<?php foreach ($data_house->house_sitting_date_next_month as $key2 => $val2) {
    foreach ($data_house->house_sitting_date_yes_no_next_month as $key2 => $val2) {


}} ?>
```

Comment: What you mean with Line A, Line B and Line C?

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this desired result?  You don't seem to have a "problem" statement so much as a requirement that you're wanting us to complete for you.

Comment: @PatrickQ I think two foreach loop will be use. I will show you what I have tried.

Comment: @Pipe Line, Line B and Line C is inside the code.

Comment: @PatrickQ Check my edit.

Comment: If you're only looking for the result for a specific date (for example, the current date), then you don't need loops at all.  Just use [`array_search()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to get the index of the date and then use that index to access the corresponding value in your yes/no array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search for your date of interest in the two sitting date arrays in `$data_house` using [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search), and then use that key to decide if the house is sitting or not (or if there is no information). That can be used to generate a string to output in the HTML:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");

$sitting_day_str_en = "Sitting day";

$not_a_sitting_day_str_en ="Not a Sitting Day";

if (($k = array_search($date, $data_house->house_sitting_date_current_month)) !== false) {
    $sitting = $data_house->house_sitting_date_yes_no_current_month[$k];
    $sitting_str_en = $sitting == 'yes' ? $sitting_day_str_en : ($sitting == 'no' ? $not_a_sitting_day_str_en : '');
}
elseif (($k = array_search($date, $data_house->house_sitting_date_next_month)) !== false) {
    $sitting = $data_house->house_sitting_date_yes_no_next_month[$k];
    $sitting_str_en = $sitting == 'yes' ? $sitting_day_str_en : ($sitting == 'no' ? $not_a_sitting_day_str_en : '');
}
else {
    // not found
    $sitting_str_en = 'No data available';
}

?>

<header class="entry-header container">
   <?php
      the_title('<h1 class="entry-title-house">', '</h1>');
    ?>
   <span class="current-date"><?php echo $date ?></span><!-- prints today's date--> // Line B 
         <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en') { ?>        <!-- English -->
                <span class="current-date-answer"><?= $sitting_str_en ?></span> // Line C                           
        <?php } ?>
</header>
```

Output (for today, 2020-02-06):

```
<header class="entry-header container">
   <h1 class="entry-title-house">House Sitting Days</h1>   <span class="current-date">2020-02-06</span><!-- prints today's date--> // Line B 
                 <!-- English -->
                <span class="current-date-answer">Sitting day</span> // Line C                           
        </header>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kfCUX)

Comment: Hi Nick, I hope all is well. I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532447/array-filter-doesnt-seems-to-work-for-words-having-apostrophe-and-dash) related to unicode and array_filter. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Comment: @flash Sorry, I'm going away for a couple of days. If it's not resolved when I come back and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you. No problem.