# How to echo all dates between two dates?

Tags: php, date

How to echo all dates between two dates?

for example:
From the date of `2020/07/29` to the date of `2020/08/02`

I want to print the results

```
2020/07/29 
2020/07/30
2020/07/31
2020/08/01
2020/08/02
```

The following code prints only to `2020/07/31`

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $from_date= $_POST['from_date'];
    $to_date  = $_POST['to_date'];

    for($from_date = $from_date ; strtotime("+$from_date Day") <=  $to_date; $from_date++){
        echo $from_date . "<br>";
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
2020/07/29
2020/07/30
2020/07/31
```

**HTML FORM**

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="date" name="from_date">
    <input type="date" name="to_date" >
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have 2 dates in PHP, how can I run a foreach loop to go through all of those days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207749/i-have-2-dates-in-php-how-can-i-run-a-foreach-loop-to-go-through-all-of-those-d)

Comment: Yes, this is required
Thank you very much