# get time intervals with time range

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to get time interval with custom start and end time variables for which i have searched and find its relevant information on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207749/i-have-2-dates-in-php-how-can-i-run-a-foreach-loop-to-go-through-all-of-those-d%5D).

I have tried the following code but its giving error`Uncaught Error: Call to a member function date() on string`

```
$start = date("H:i",strtotime('08:30 AM'));
$end = date("H:i",strtotime('06:00 PM'));
for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i->modify(' +30 MINUTE')){
    echo $i->date("H:i");
}
```

Comment: An error you say? So what error are you getting please

Comment: What is `$start_time`? You have `$start` defined, but it's a string, not a DateTime object, and you don't show if/where `$start_time` or `$end_time` is defined.

Comment: If you are going to use examples, then you cannot mix and match bits of the examples you found

Comment: @RiggsFolly plz check the updated question

Comment: `$start` and `$end` are strings, not DateTime objects. Therefore, you cannot use `date()` or `modify()` on them

Comment: Please check the multiple answers in the link you gave us

Comment: The accepted answer in the Question you link to need only the SMALLEST change to work for you `$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('30 minute');`

Comment: @aynber How can i do it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried like that. Its giving this error`Uncaught TypeError: DatePeriod::__construct() accepts (DateTimeInterface, DateInterval, int [, int]), or (DateTimeInterface, DateInterval, DateTime [, int]), or (string [, int]) as arguments`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the builtin `\DateTime` class and the `\DateInterval` class as well

```
$begin = new DateTime('08:30:00');
$end = new DateTime('12:45:00');

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('30 minute');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("H:i\n");
}
```

RESULTS

```
08:30
09:00
09:30
10:00
10:30
11:00
11:30
12:00
12:30
```

And if the time roles over to another day something like this

```
$begin = new DateTimeImmutable('2022-03-01 16:00:00');
$end = (new DateTime())->createFromImmutable($begin)->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->settime(8,30,0);

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('30 minute');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("d/m/Y H:i\n");
}
```

Comment: The class is `DateTime` not `DATETIME`. Or to be more precise `\DateTime`.